# Every subset of a finite set is finite.. confused why this proof is wrong..

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prop. Every subset of a finite set is finite

Proof. Let A,B sets and suppose B is a finite set. Also let $A \subseteq B$

If B = $\varnothing$, A is also $\varnothing$ and is finite.

If B $\neq \varnothing$, there exists a bijection f:B->[n] for n $\in N$

Since $A \subseteq B$, the inclusion mapping I: A->B defined f(a)=a for a $\in A$ exists and clearly this is an injection.

Then we can have f$\circ$I: A->[n], which is injective.

But we know there is a bijection between A and its image in f$\circ$I, meaning that A bijectively maps to the subset of [n], which is finite.

Hence A is also finite.

I was told that this is a good setup and the part where I said "the subset of [n], which is finite" is the meat of the proof..? but was also told that I didn't get the proof right.

Any help on this please?

Comment: You are assuming what you want to prove, it seems. You have $[n]$, which I'm taking to be $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ (a finite set), and you have a subset of that finite set. How do you know the subset is finite?

Comment: Your idea seems good enough, but your notation (especially the $\to[n]$) confuses me to a point where I'm not certain.

Comment: As @Clayton says. If you haven't proved that every subset of $[n]$ is finite, then you're using the statement that you need to prove. Therefore, you should first prove this for $[n]$ by showing that if $A\subseteq[n]$, then for some $m\leq n$, $A$ has a bijection with $[m]$. Then your proof is fine.

Comment: Can you confirm that by [n] you mean {1,2,....,n}?  I'm not familiar with the notation.  You have prove there is an bijection between A and some subset of [n], but you haven't proven that every subset of [n] is finite.  Hypothetically the bijection of A could be to an infinite subset of [n].  Hypothetically, that is.  It's "obvious" that's impossible.  But that's the heart of the proof.

Comment: yes [n] is {1,2,......n}, a finite set

Comment: @AsafKaragila so I get it now I was assuming things that I had to prove, but still I am not sure how I should proceed what you said

Comment: Hint: Use induction to construct the required bijection for subsets of [n].

Comment: so I prove there is a bijection between the set A and all subsets of [n]. But now I wonder, If I also have to prove that every subset of [n] is finite? If I don't prove it, even if I know there is a bijection between the set A and every subset of [n], wouldn't it be unclear to argue that A is finite?